# Using Java's Stream.reduce() to calculate sum of powers gives unexpected result

Tags: java-8, java-stream

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

int i = list.stream().mapToInt(e -> e)
            .reduce((x, y) -> (int) Math.pow(x, list.size()) + (int) Math.pow(y, list.size()))
            .getAsInt();
        System.out.println(i);
```

The result of this operation should be 1*1*1 + 2*2*2 + 3*3*3 = 36. But instead I get i = 756. What's wrong? What should I change in order reduce() to work correctly?

Comment: Reduce absolutely doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: read the doc again: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator- (in particular, check what are the arguments to the accumulator)

Comment: Yes, I see I misunderstood it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't even need to reduce

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

int i = list.stream()
         .mapToInt(e -> (int) Math.pow(e, list.size()))
         .sum();
```

Comment: best answer, least number of boilerplate code. Better than using reduce, and better than using collect(Collectors.summingInt)

Comment: Technically a `sum()` is still a reduction it's just one built into the API

Comment: @RobV: sure, but “*least number of boilerplate code*” only refers to how much you have write to get there.

Comment: @Rob, yes, I was going to mention this, `sum()` is just a specialized reduce. It even mentions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) that sum is a form of reduction

Answer (score 19):

The solution was already posted, but you get 756,

because the first call to reduce  (x,y) with (1,2) is

```
1^3+2^3=9
```

then you reduce with (x,y) with (9,3)

```
9^3+3^3=756
```

BTW, since exponentiation is not associative, you can also get other values. For example, when using a parallel stream, I also got `42876` as result.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
int i = list.stream()
            .map(e -> (int) Math.pow(e, list.size()))
            .reduce((x, y) -> x + y)
            .get();
```

Comment: `.reduce((x, y) -> x + y)` aka `sum()`

Comment: @njzk2 you'd need `mapToInt` for that.

Comment: sure, but why wouldn't you use `mapToInt` in this case?

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue))` instead of `reduce((x, y) -> x + y)`.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake was found, the new code is below:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

int i = list.stream().mapToInt(e -> e)
             .map(e -> (int) Math.pow(e, list.size()))
             .reduce((x, y) -> x + y)
             .getAsInt();
System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

your logic is wrong, that is why you got 756

```
int i = list.stream()
            .mapToInt(e -> e)
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .reduce(0,(x, y) -> x + (int) Math.pow(y, list.size()));
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong too. The function you are passing to `reduce` is not associative, hence, it only happens to work in sequential streams.

Comment: The example you gave was to work on sequence. So I just wrote in couple of minutes.

Comment: I didn’t give any example. I’m just a reader who tells you, that you are using the Stream API in a way that violates the contract and just happens to produce the expected result in certain circumstances, which doesn’t make it a correct solution.

Comment: Fyi: answer i wrote was something I remembered from oracle reference.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html